# left join where the primary key has both integer and string

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to join two tables where the primary keys have both integer and string value. When I use left join using id column as primary key I am getting the records related to the integer only.I would like to get the output for both integer and string as shown in the output. Can anyone assist please.

select t1.*
,t2.Position
from t1
left join t2
on t1.id=t2.id;

I am getting the output which related to id (integer) only.I would like to get the output for both integer id and string id.

[image]

Comment: This is not JOIN, this is UNION DISTINCT. And the table with string type data must be first, or you must CAST the column to the string datatype in the most upper UNION 's subquery. Of course, all final column values (including "numbers") will have string data type.

Comment: @ Akina, how to use UNION DISTINCT here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining tables where primary key are both interger and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795074/joining-tables-where-primary-key-are-both-interger-and-string)

Answer (score 0):

> how to use UNION DISTINCT here – Nrad

```
SELECT id FROM table1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id FROM table2
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(id AS CHAR) AS id FROM table2
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT id FROM table1
```

`DISTINCT` keyword is optional and may be skipped in both cases.

If you need the ordering shown then add

```
ORDER BY id + 0 = 0, id
```

to the end of a query.

---

> i have some other different columns in both table that I need to take. – Nrad

```
SELECT id, 
       COALESCE (t1.name, t2.name) name, 
       t1.salary, 
       t2.position, 
       t1.department
FROM ( SELECT id FROM table1
       UNION DISTINCT
       SELECT id FROM table2 ) t0
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (id)
```

Comment: @ Akina, i have some other different columns in both table that I need to take. I think I cannot use union in this case. I'd like to use LEFT JOIN. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: @Nrad Create new question and publish real task, with real structures and data examples (in textual form, not as pictures!!! obfuscate if needed), instead of non-adequately simplified model. *I'd like to use LEFT JOIN.* Use... but it will not solve in SHOWN case.

Comment: @ Akina, Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the input tables and expected output table. I am not determined to use left join. Whatever solution is the best, please assist.

Comment: @Nrad Please replace screenshots with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with some example data (2-3 records, all columns filled) and show desired result for this data. And tell/show what if there are different `name` values for the same `id` in different tables (do not tell that it is not possible - or prove this by the constraint which guarantees this).

Comment: @ Akina,I have added the query. Can you please have a look.

Comment: @Nrad Updated, check.

Comment: @ Akina, It shows an error at the last line. "id in USING clause not found on left side of join". Just wanted to know where should i use t0. Thanks.

Comment: @ Akina, I'm using Google BigQuery.

Comment: @Nrad *I'm using Google BigQuery* If so why you have tagged the question as MySQl-relative? *"id in USING clause not found on left side of join"* Try to replace `USING (id)` WITH `ON t0.id = tx.id`.

Comment: @ Akina, When I select id only it gives me the correct value, but when I select the other field from both tables, it takes longer time and I cannot get the result.

Comment: In general queries using Join may be computationally taxing and might require a long time to finish. Is it currently working well for you? Or do you still experience problems when selecting more fields than the id? If so, do you encounter any explicit error message? Please update the question to reflect the current query you are trying and explain clearly what is the issue you are experiencing so we can help you further.